# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\veiw() error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem in my starting codes in Laravel,
it's my error :

*Error
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\veiw()*

it's my web.php (routes page) :

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/users', 'UserController@user');
```

and it's my Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function user() {
        return veiw('index');
    }
}
```

Hope you help me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mistyped `view`: It is `view`, not `veiw`

Comment: thank you a lot xDDDDD I have problem with this about 1 week :D xDDD thank you